# Pronunciation of silent consonants in English names

Tags: pronunciation, names

My surname ends in a silent H, which makes the last two letters, TH, pronounced like a hard T. I've read that Japanese tends to "make close approximations (of names) based on spelling, not pronunciation". So, depending on which is true, my name ends in either "to" or "tsu". Which one is more accurate?

Comment: You heard wrong then.  Take the name "Charles" for example.  We write it チャールズ as an English name and シャルル as a French name.  That is 100% based on the pronunciation as the spelling is identical.

Comment: @l'électeur Then why is my name -ALWAYS- written as レオ when リオ is clearly the closer pronunciation?

Answer (score 1):

No, its actually the opposite.  You use katakana (normally) and get as close as you can phonetically to the original pronunciation.  ツ would end your name like "gets" so you'd have an S sound at the end which is probably not what you'd want.  I think hard T would probably use one of タ、ト、テ, which is ta, to, and te, respectively.  No matter what, I think you'll have to end with an added vowel, which is not uncommon when trying to pronounce foreign words.

You can try an online site like here http://www.japanese-name-translation.com/ to help you get an idea.  If its a common last name it may be that someone has already figured it out and there's a "normal" way to write it.  If not, you can tweak it to get as close to the original pronunciation as possible.

Comment: Yeah, when I moved to Japan everyone I meet definitely tried write my name based on pronunciation, not how it's spelled. It's a pretty unusual/hard to say in Japanese name. Actually, that's where my user name comes from - some friends named me Haruko because my name - first and last - was a struggle :-D

Comment: @Harukogirl Isn't it considered an honor when Japanese people shorten your name? :-)

Comment: Haha, I took it as a good thing when they named me. But my point was that my real name sounds NOTHING like Haruko- it's a gaelic orgin name, lots of consonants. They tried to go off of the sounds and put it in katakana, but.... Haruko stuck once someone suggested it. I did get called "Haru-chan" and just "Haruko" by a few closer friends as well :)

Comment: @Harukogirl just curious -- what is your name?

Comment: @Harukogirl - Yeah, my name is pretty murderous as well. You end up with ウィリアム, so I just went with ウィル.

Comment: @xyzjayne last name is pronounced Spray -g (as in goat). It's spelled to totally different, but that's how it's said. There's no vowel sound after "g." They wrote it as スプライーグ, but seemed to really struggle with saying it.

Answer (score 0):

You are partly true.

> Peter Graham

who is eminent composer in Wind Orchestra and Brass Bands musics.
often translated and written as below.

> ピーター•グラハム

Also a famous poker player

> Evelyn Ng

Many believe her name is pronounced like below

> エブリン•ング？

her sir name rarely read properly.

It's not the all the case that we notate specific name in katakana based on its actual pronunciations.